# Bootstrap 4.0 Collapsible Navbar with Fixed Top not Wrapping Menu Tabs

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am attempting to re-build a site using bootstrap but I either am doing something wrong or may have hit a bug.

In short, I'm using the sample collapse navbar from the bootstrap samples ([Navbar-Toggler](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#toggler)). I'm using a javascript to fill in the menu items. The thing is that after a certain number of tabs is added, it continues to add them inline instead of wrapping the tabs. I've added a jsfiddle that should show the same behavior. It builds 40 tabs which should make 2 or 3 rows, but instead it puts them all inline.

Any thoughts?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>            
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>                
</head>

<body onLoad="addTabs()">
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="myNavbarEntries">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>      
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>  

<script type = "text/javascript">
    function addTabs(){
        var v = document.getElementById("myNavbarEntries");     
     for(var x=0; x<20;x++){
        var a = document.createElement("li");
        var q = (x>0)?"nav-item":"nav-item active";
        a.className = q;
        a.innerHTML = '<a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">New Tab</a>'
        v.appendChild(a);        
     }
    }    
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ut8awbzs/5/

Answer (score 0):

all this needs to go at the bottom before the closing body tag 
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: I did add that correction to my file (and I edited the file above) but, much like the fiddle, the behavior persists.